# Do I need to run romex wires if it's in conduit?

Tags: wiring

I'm wondering if I will be able to just pull single wires since I'm going to be putting the wires in conduit. I'm going to need 120 V. I was also wondering if my box is metal, would I just be able to ground outlet to the box and not need another ground wire going back to the breaker box?

Answer (score 3):

Metal conduit can be used/is used as ground. Extra ground wire is not needed.

If plastic boxes are used, think there are ground connections to attach to conduit.

From other questions on here, a cable is much harder to pull though conduit than wires.

Need wires made for conduit, can't just strip the outer covering from a cable and use those wires.